# Is it possible to integrate Node.js in a java web application for some functionalities like for chat functionalities?

Tags: node.js, jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to integrate node.js chat application using socket.io framework to the JSF web application running on JBoss server. Can you please give any sugessions like how to do it.

Comment: can you clarify what is it that you actually mean by integration. what needs to work?

Comment: Like i want to add chat functionality using node.js to my web application

Comment: node.js is a different web server from your java web server. if by integration you mean an ui integration, you could use something like an HTML frame or just regular hyperlinks going back and forth between the servers. is that what you mean?

Comment: Ya. Like I've JSF command button say Chat. When i click that node.js chat application should run. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have two servers running on the same domain but on different ports, say node.js on 8888 and JBoss on 8080. In an HTML page on JBoss, have a regular hyperlink pointing to chat server on `yourservername:8888/chaturl`, and on chat exit, return to your JBoss app.

Or use a frame if you need to embed the chat app to your page in JBoss. But rather not frames.

Comment: Thank u :) Let me try that :)

Comment: That works fine. For that mannualy I've to start nodejs server . Is there any way to run nodejs file(Its java script file) within my JSF web application?? Like when I click chat button nodejs server should start running if it is not running already

Comment: @user2354187 you should configure nodejs server to start the same way you configure jboss to start, so whenever jboss is running, node.js server is running. automatically on server startup, usually. it does not run and should not be running within JSF web application but as its own server.

Comment: How to communicate between java web server and node.js server. Like if i want conversation log in JSF application ? I can write it into database but how to maintain consistency of database if both application change database simultaneously?

Comment: @user2354187 this is what I asked you for when I asked what you mean by integration. Please list all the points that you actually mean when you want the servers to interact which each other. What you're talking about now is NOT an UI integration.

Comment: I want to save conversation log into database from nodejs server and how to read it from my java web server. And also i want to maintain database consistency.

Comment: your question makes no sense. database consistency applies for actions that modify the database, if you just read it from java it does not affect consistency. you can read from database just as you regularely would. writing would need to use proper transactions when node.js app does it.